# Parent div of a position fixed img has no height / Can't apply overflow hidden if height > than viewport size

Tags: css, position, height, parent-child, fixed

I'm trying to achieve the last piece of my general template for articles in a wordpress blog.

I've got an header/menu which is `position: fixed`.

Then I have a div `.postThumbnail` with a child img which is `position: fixed` so the following content can overlap the img when scrolling.

I also have a div that copy the img'height as the image is fixed.

Fact is, this could be a lot easier if `.postThumbnail` had an height, but **it's value is equal to 0**.

I do not know why.

What I intend to do is to set `.postThumbnail`'s **max-height** equal to the height of the viewport minus the height of the header/menu, so if an image is taller than the viewport, it won't overflow and the following content which can be scrolled will appears right after the image (and not after the total height of the image).

Basically, I need to define `.postThumbnail`'s height so I can apply an `overflow:hidden`.

Any idea?

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seeane/xcs2ksph/12) so you can actually see what I'm talking about.

Some of the current code :

```
#single\.php .postThumbnail img {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 640px;
  height: auto;
}

#single\.php .postThumbnailGhost { /*keep as security even if no content is integrated*/
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

What I need to achieve :

```
#single\.php .postThumbnail{
max-height: calc(100vh - 48px);
overflow: hidden;
}
```

With this fixed, I could fix the rest of the page as the content's `min-height` must be equal to the image's height in order to cover it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I really simplified everything since I don't need a `.postThumbnailGhost` in this new version.

I also made it in Jquery as I couldn't do it fully in CSS ( :'( ).

Here is the script that is doing the job :

```
 function refreshDynamicContent(){
  $('.postThumbnail').height($('.wp-post-image').height());
  $('.postThumbnail').css('max-height', $(window).height() - ($('header').height()));
  $('#post').css('min-height', $('.postThumbnail').height());
  }
  refreshDynamicContent();
  $(window).on("resize", refreshDynamicContent);
```

New [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seeane/xcs2ksph/13/)

And I don't need an overflow anymore because I can set the `height` to the window's `height`!

YAY!